# http commits with subversion

Tags: svn

The normal way to use subversion is by typing the svn commands in the command prompt. Is there a way to, for example, make commits or updates via a web browser interface? I'm imagining that you can type in the URL for the repository and it would bring up a page with buttons which allow you to check code out, commit etc, without having to ever use the svn commands.

I am aware of TortoiseSVN, which doesn't do exactly this, but does create a very nice subversion interface. But this only works on Microsoft Windows and I am looking for something that will work for a Mac and Linux.

Comment: SVN used to support WebDAV, which let you download and commit, but this was never very sophisticated, and I don't know whether it's even still supported. OTOH, there certainly are GUI clients for Linux, and I'd presume this to be the case for OSX, too.

Comment: Take a look here for Subversion clients on Mac OS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899/best-subversion-client-for-mac-os

Comment: From what I read on the web, it didn't sound like you could could use WebDAV to commit, it really only helped to make the files in the repository accessable to others to see... And do you have any GUI clients to suggest? I have been searching a lot on the web and nothing seems to replicate what I see TortoiseSVN doing, which I like a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a cross-platform client for svn, maybe check some of [these](http://alternativeto.net/software/tortoisesvn/) .
(for Linux you will find there are also built in plugins for thunar, nautilus and dolphin).

For a complete solution in php, why not try [here](http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/) or [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) for building your own solution from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

- write a plugin for your preferred web browser that works with local files in the way you want to, or
- make a web page to get the code to your system (checkout, update) and program a server side script which commits on posting a file (commit)...

or, if you just want a TortoiseSVN for unix, you can give **RapidSVN** a try.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X you can use [svnX](http://code.google.com/p/svnx/) as an OpenSource subversion GUI.